# c# Getting ip addresses of all network interfaces,getting more than one ipv4 addresses per adapter

Tags: c#, networking, ipv6, ipv4

In my app I need to display IP addresses of each available (wifi or ethernet) adapter.

Problem is I get more then one IP address per adapter, and last one I get (per adapter) is one I'm looking for.

I dont know what for are first two (usually they are first two) IP addresses and how to get "real" IP address. I compared these two IP addresses that I get before "real" one with CMD and "ipconfig" command and they are not mentioned there, so its not default gateway, subnet mask,local Ipv6 or public IP address.

**This is what my app outputs:**

[image]

**This is what I want:**

[image]

**Code I use:**

```cs
foreach (NetworkInterface inf in devs)
{
    if (inf.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || inf.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
    {
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation address in inf.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (address.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                MessageBox.Show(address.Address.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your output

Comment: Im sorry,I edited question now. @Junaid

Comment: What is devs?  How do you know you're getting more than one address per adapter?

Comment: NetworkInterface[] devs= NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces(); sorry forgot that

Comment: I'm unclear by what you "real" IP address. Any IP address assigned to an interface is a real IP address. With IPv6, it is very easy to assign multiple, Global IP addresses per interface.

Comment: I posted pictures in my question now.I keep getting 3 ip addresses per adapter when using code above.First two(i compared with ipconfig in cmd) are not either ipv4 or ipv6 addresses of certain adapter,last address i get is ipv4(i colored it red on picture).So by real i mean ipv4 or ipv6,which I get last,but i still dont know what first two addresses represent

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer on how to get IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) per adapter.

```
NetworkInterface[] intf = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach(NetworkInterface device in intf)
{
    IPAddress ipv6Address = device.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[0].Address; //This will give ipv6 address of certain adapter
    IPAddress ipv4Address = device.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[1].Address; //This will give ipv4 address of certain adapter
}
```

Comment: You need to understand that interfaces will almost certainly have multiple IPv6 addresses. Every IPv6 interface will have a Link-Local IPv6 address, and probably one or more of Global and/or ULA addresses. Most IPv4 interfaces only have a single address, but IPv6 can (and in many cases, must) have multiple addresses.